lxqt-session starts an unwanted file manager
I used to use Compiz as my window manager (no desktop environment) on Suse Tumbleweed.
When I knew that I can use the LXQT desktop with a window manager of my choice, I installed it and at the first startup I was presented with a list of the installed WM and I chose Compiz.
Everything is quite nice, my Compiz configuration was preserved and I will probably use this setup for a long time.
BUT
When the LXQT session (/usr/bin/lxqt-session, an ELF binary) starts, by default it starts the LXQT file manager like pcmanfm-qt --desktop and I don't want it.
How can I prevent /usr/bin/lxqt-session from starting pcmanfm-qt --desktop


From the command line execute lxqt-config-session.
In the first panel that is shown to you uncheck, under LXQT Modules, the "Desktop" entry.
Logout.
Login.
Enjoy.

